# mismatched input '(' expecting QUOTEDSTRING

Tags: apache-pig

I have One data set given below

1,2,3

4,5,6

Grunt command I have tried 
1.  LOAD ('text') using PigStorage(",");
2. A = LOAD ("text") using PigStorage(',');
3. LOAD ('text') using PigStorage(',') as (f1:int,f2:int,f3:int);

All command returns same error.

ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:   mismatched input '(' expecting QUOTEDSTRING

Comment: A = LOAD 'employees.data' using PigStorage('|');

Comment: `A = LOAD 'employees.data' using PigStorage(',') as (f1:int, f2:int, f3:int);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation, it's easy

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#load